# python xml parser minidom memory usage

Tags: python, minidom

I recently use minidom to parse some xml files.

The funny thing is it takes me 8G memroy to read a 56MB file, which is relative flat, i.e., most of the nodes are in the same level.

Why is this true?

Comment: Maybe you have some nasty entity expansions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs is an extreme case of that.

Comment: Perhaps you can post some of your code so that we can take a look at it. My guess is your are building a lot of immutable objects in diff format representing same data without collecting them.

Comment: [objgraph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objgraph) is a terrific tool for inspecting process objects. I'd start there, and see which objects are created in the millions/billions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one to face [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787026/memory-leak-parsing-xml-using-xml-dom-minidom).

From my humble opinion, the main reason `minidom` based program consume lot of memory is due to the fact lot of `minidom` functions are implemented recursively (recursion and memory usage are generally not good friends).

I advice you to opt for other Python XML parser libraries which are faster (notably [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)).